# Kubernetes nginx ingress controller cannot upload size more than 1mb

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, controller

I am fairly new to GCP and I have a rest URI to upload large files.
I have a ngress-nginx-controller service and want to change it to upload files larger than 1mb and set a limit.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"controller","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/managed-by":"Helm","app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/version":"0.35.0","helm.sh/chart":"ingress-nginx-2.13.0"},"name":"ingress-nginx-controller","namespace":"ingress-nginx"},"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local","ports":[{"name":"http","port":80,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":"http"},{"name":"https","port":443,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":"https"}],"selector":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"controller","app.kubernetes.io/instance":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx"},"type":"LoadBalancer"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2020-09-21T18:37:27Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.35.0
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.13.0
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
```

This is the error it throws :

```
<html>
<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you need to increase the body size of files you upload via the ingress controller, you need to add an annotation to your ingress resource:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 8m
```

Documentation available here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-max-body-size

Comment: thanks for the answer : this is the service tho : shall I add it under annotations here in the file i pasted above ? @blenderfox

Comment: You put it under the _ingress_ resource you are trying to attach. The nginx ingress controller allows annotations per ingress (so different ingresses can have different upload limits, for example) or globally (each ingress has the same upload limit). There should be very little need to patch the ingress controller _service_ -- you would patch the ingress the controller is routing the traffic for.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [ingress-nginx helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx)

you need to set the values in the following way

```
controller:
 replicaCount: 2
 service:
 annotations:
  ...
 config:
   proxy-body-size: "8m"
```

Comment: This would set it globally, so all ingresses would have this setting unless overridden by an annotation.